# How to send array by POST method to server?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am trying to send array as parameter to server but server is not receiving. Server have to receive two arrays that I am sending. But in server they are not appear ?? I dont know is it my mistake or mistake in the server ??
My array name is testAns and testQuest and I have to send it to parameters: answer and quest.
my Code:

```
let userID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID")
let artID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "index")
let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.someurls.kz/modules/CheckTestF.php");
var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
var testAns = [Int]()
var testQuest = [Int]()
testAns = [131,123,23]
testQuest = [123,233,232]
let postString = "uID=97B436E41&idUser=\(userID!)&art_id=\(artID!)&answer=\(testAns)&quest=\(testQuest)"
print(postString)
print(testAns,testQuest)
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
    if error != nil
    {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }
    do {
        _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: refer more before asking basic questions.

Comment: @Ragul I have edited please help if you know, if something is not understandable let me to know

Comment: have look at my answer and let me know if you have any further assistance.

Comment: It strongly depends on how your server receives array. Please show the server side code or the server's API reference. Or else you may need to play long lasting guess game...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know how to encode that array on your server side.
but temporary you can try this way and check your database.

```
let postString = "uID=97B436E41&idUser=\(userID!)&art_id=\(artID!)&answer[0]=131&answer[1]=123&quest[0]=123&quest[1]=233"
```

Comment: you need to serialize answer array and then append to postString.

Comment: it's php array at server side.that's way need to send like that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) that is very popular at this time that is advanced version of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
Also, I am sharing the method that will help you to hit API, You have to pass only the dictionary object in this method and this will give you the response in two blocks and you can use them as per requirements.

**1: unReachable()**

**2: handler(responseDict)**

```
//MARK: *********** HIT POST SERVICE IN JSON FORM***********
    func hitPostServiceJsonForm(_ params:Dictionary<String,Any>,unReachable:(() -> Void),handler:@escaping ((Dictionary<String,Any>?) -> Void)) {
        if networkReachable() == false {
            unReachable()
        }
        let BASE_URL = "http://mydoamain"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: BASE_URL)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)

        print(BASE_URL)
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
            //print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            //print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                    print("Json Response: \(jsonDict)") // serialized json response
                    handler(jsonDict)
                }
                else{
                    handler(nil)
                }
                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Server Response: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                handler(nil)
                print(error)
                break
            }
        }
    }



func networkReachable() -> Bool {
     return (NetworkReachabilityManager()?.isReachable)!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the your array to json string then try to send it to server

func post_array(){

```
    let userID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID")
    let artID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "index")
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.someurls.kz/modules/CheckTestF.php");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    var testAns = [Int]()
    var testQuest = [Int]()
    testAns = [131,123,23]
    testQuest = [123,233,232]

    var tempAns : NSString = ""
    do {
        let arrJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: testAns, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let string = NSString(data: arrJson, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        tempAns = string! as NSString
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
    }

    var tempQuest : NSString = ""
    do {
        let arrJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: testQuest, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let string = NSString(data: arrJson, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        tempQuest = string! as NSString
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
    }
    let postString = "uID=97B436E41&idUser=\(userID!)&art_id=\(artID!)&answer=\(tempAns)&quest=\(tempQuest)"
    print(postString)
    print(testAns,testQuest)
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        do {
            _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: var tempAns : NSString = ""
    do {
        let arrJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: testAns, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let string = NSString(data: arrJson, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        tempAns = string! as NSString
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
    }